# Create table of contents without creating separate chapter for it

Tags: table-of-contents

I don't want to create separate chapter for table of contents.

Standard `\tableofcontents` creates it.

So how can I get from `\tableofcontents` only its content, without chapters?

Or how can I remove page with chapter title that it creates?

Comment: The `\tableofcontents` usually does not create a chapter. In my point of view your question is totally unclear. Please provide a compilable document, reduced to the minimal extent, that shows your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

1. If you want `\tableofcontents` to create a section you can try simply `{\let\chapter\section \tableofcontents}` or
2. you can redefine it with
   `\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\@starttoc{toc}}` and then you can do any thing with it and `\contensname`.

---

**Code**:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}
\section{bla}
\section{bla bla}
\section{blabla 2}
\end{document}
```

**Example**

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\fbox{%
\textsc{\contentsname}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\@starttoc{toc}
\end{minipage}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}
\section{bla}
\section{bla bla}
\section{blabla 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]